# Remote Validation for Uniqueness in MVC3 is not working with Editable mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC3. I am using ItemNo field as Unique one. but that field can be editable. If i create a value in ItemNo with the existing value then the remote validation works fine. If i do this in Editable mode it repeats the same thing as it did like create Action method.

Here is my Validation controller:

```
 <!-- language: lang-js -->
 [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
 public class ValidationController : Controller
 {
   ItemControlDBContext db = new ItemControlDBContext();
   public JsonResult IsItemNoAvailable(string ItemNo)
 {
   List<string> ItemNos = (from no in db.Item select no.ItemNo).ToList();
   if (ItemNos.Contains(ItemNo.ToLower()))
 {
   return Json("The ItemNo is already available. Try another.",  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
   return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }

 }
```

Here is my Model Class

```
[Required]
[Remote("IsItemNoAvailable", "Validation")]
[Editable(true)]
public string ItemNo { get; set; }
```

Pls suggest me in which way i can achieve this in editable mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make use of [RemoteAttribute.AdditionalFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.additionalfields%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) property, and pass `Id` of your model for validation. Than in action, you should check db not only for `ItemNo`, but for `Id` too.

```
[Required]
[Remote("IsItemNoAvailable", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
[Editable(true)]
public string ItemNo { get; set; }
```

And controller method (note that I also re-factored your select)

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    ItemControlDBContext db = new ItemControlDBContext();
    public JsonResult IsItemNoAvailable(string ItemNo, int ID=0)
    {
        bool itemNoAlreadyExists = db.Item.Any(item => item.ItemNo == itemNo && item.ID != ID);

        if (itemNoAlreadyExists)
        {
            return Json("The ItemNo is already available. Try another ItemNo.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

Comment: > If i add Id as another parameter then the remote validation is not working properly.

Comment: @user1495547 adding parameter is right way of doing that. Does id get passed correctly? You should debug issue and give more details :)

Comment: If i add ItemNO and Id as 2 parameters then the edit Action works fine. But the create action method is not calling the remote validation. Even its not calling the Validation JSON method at all. I think the create event dont have Id. so that the Create Action is not calling validation.

Comment: Thank you man its working after i add Id field to 0(Zero) as default. Thanks.